# Using jQuery to expand a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, libraries

relatively new to JavaScript and jQuery. I would like to introduce a feature in the site I am building, in which there is a text and when a link is clicked within that text, a video appears. I don't want the video to appear on a different window or another tab to open, what I would like is that the rest of the text just moves down to allow space for the video to be displayed. Then, when the video finishes it disappears and the text comes back to its orginal place. I know there must be some library out there, i just would like being pointed to it. Thanks.
P

Comment: Hi, please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the Fancybox jQuery plugin would solve your issue: http://fancybox.net/
It supports displaying images, gallery, iframe, html and video in a lightbox.

First you have to load jQuery before adding the Fancybox plugin.
See below:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Website</title>
    <link href="path/to/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <li><a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=opj24KnzrWo">Youtube</a></li>
    <li><a class="fancybox-media" href="http://vimeo.com/47480346">Vimeo</a></li>

    <script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="path/to/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
    <script src="path/to/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
    <script src="path/to/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
(function($) {
    $('.fancybox-media')
        .attr('rel', 'media-gallery')
        .fancybox({
            openEffect : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',
            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',

            arrows : false,
            helpers : {
                media : {},
                buttons : {}
            }
        });
}(jQuery);
```

Download the plugin (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license) and check the demo for more information.